# Save Windows start screen layout (as a template)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, start-screen

Is there a way for me to SAVE my "start menu" layout to a file (xml?), meaning the grouping and ordering of the elements on the Start screen.

TO CLARIFY... I am aware of and understand the "roaming" profile capability / behavior which support syncing your user preferences between devices.

I like the way my start screen is set up.... I want to be able save it, switch things around, and then restore my previous layout.

Almost like how you can save "templates" of layouts on some Android devices.

Is it in the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back up the following files (whichever ones exist), then restore them and see if it works:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.itemdata-ms
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.itemdata-ms.bak

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.itemdata-ms
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.itemdata-ms.bak
```

After restoring you might need to restart Explorer from Task Manager:

[image: 1]

Comment: So does it work then??

Comment: Haven't tried. Will try today

Answer (score 0):

There are some PowerShell commands that allow you to export the start menu and re-import it.  Arguably you could manipulate the file and upload an identical file to multiple enviroments!

```
$sitename = "xyz"
Export-StartLayout -Path "$sitename.json"
# before running the import, edit the file in some way. 
# or just clone it to other servers.
# ... then ....
Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath "$sitename.json" -MountPath "c:\"
```

The file looks like this:

[image: code file, xyz.json]